# Bash invoking awk to write to textfile

Tags: bash

Consider the output of `iostat`

```
$ iostat
Linux 2.6.31-20-generic-pae (ubuntu-9-10)   04/08/2010  _i686_  (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2.38    0.07    0.66    0.39    0.00   96.51

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               6.93       131.80        85.02    1347350     869177
```

How can I read the values of the line starting with `sda` into a bash array (ignoring the `sda` string)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please spend some time reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. For now, I have improved your question but if you want your question, to be taken seriously, you will probably need to spend more effort on them.

Comment: your subject line doesn't seem to have anything to do with your stated question in the last line. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sed` to find the line and remove the string from it. Use `$( ... )` to capture its output to a variable.

```
$ sda=( $(iostat | sed -n '/^sda/ s/^sda// p') )
$ echo ${sda[0]}
6.93
$ echo ${sda[1]}
131.80
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
x=($(iostat|grep -Po '^sda\s*\K.*'))
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
Linux 2.6.31-20-generic-pae (ubuntu-9-10)   04/08/2010  _i686_  (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2.38    0.07    0.66    0.39    0.00   96.51

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               6.93       131.80        85.02    1347350     869177

kent$  x=($(cat f|grep -Po '^sda\s*\K.*'))   

kent$  echo ${#x}
5

kent$  echo ${x[3]}
85.02

kent$  echo ${x[@]}
6.93 131.80 85.02 1347350 869177
```